# How do I get a game object's rotation values that is displayed in the editor in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently really confused regarding how rotation (and eulerAngles) work in Unity, and I feel like I am missing something fundamental.

I have a game object `Emma`, which has a script that constantly prints out the rotation (`mainObject` points to the `Emma` object):

```
"emma1 x=" + this.transform.eulerAngles.x + " y=" + this.transform.eulerAngles.y + " z=" + this.transform.eulerAngles.z);
"emma2 x=" + mainObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x + " y=" + mainObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y + " z=" + mainObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
"emma3 x=" + mainObject.transform.rotation.x + " y=" + mainObject.transform.rotation.y + " z=" + mainObject.transform.rotation.z);
"emma4 x=" + mainObject.transform.localEulerAngles.x + " y=" + mainObject.transform.localEulerAngles.y + " z=" + mainObject.transform.localEulerAngles.z);
```

In the editor, I have rotated `Emma` to `x=235 y=20 z=70`.

[image]

However, the output becomes `x=305 y=200 z=250`.

[image]

Regardless how I rotate `Emma` the editor values makes sense for me, but the print output is understandable for me.

Another example is editor `x=250 y=180 z=100` but the output becomes `x=290 y=5 z=280`.
[image]

Even if I rotate one axis in the editor, for example `x` in the script, all 3 can change (`x, z, y`) which makes no sense to me.

**My fundamental problem is;**
I want, via scripting, be able to rotate Emma towards a specific direction (like towards a door in the flat). I can figure out the values by rotating Emma in the editor, but if I am not able to apply those values via scripting, then how else would one do it.

So my questions are:

1. Why do they differ? I read somewhere that the editor shows the `localEulerAngles` but apparently this is not true.
2. How do I print in a script the values that are shown in the editor? Am I not using the correct functions?
3. If I want a specific direction shown in the editor, what functions should I be using to set that rotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to make sense of this, I have personally come to this conclusion:

There is no straightforward mapping between the editor's `X/Y/Z` rotation values and `.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x/y/z` values.

For example, `.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y` keep changing even though, I might not have modified it, because of Unity's internal handling of rotations, meaning it is not a good way to answer the question "What Y rotation does this object have?".

**My solution**

In order to abstract away Unit's own (magical) logic, I have created my own *Single Source of Truth* by creating my own variables on moving objects.

Simplified implementation:

```
public class Emma : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float currentRotX = 0;
    private float currentRotY = 0;
    private float currentRotZ = 0;

    void Update() {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(currentRotX , currentRotY, currentRotZ);
        // or
       transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(currentRotX , currentRotY, currentRotZ));
    }


}
```

Meaning, if I want my object to have a specific rotation, I assign my own variables:

```
void lookAtDoor(){
    this.currentRotX = 123;
}
```

and If I want to know what rotation my object currently has, it would be:

```
boolean isLookingAtTV(){
    return this.currentRotX == 123;
}
```

Meaning, I have creating my own Single Source of Truth abstraction layer on top of however Unity wants to do it.

This has saved me a lot of headache and I hope this pattern helps the next person reading this!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to find a direct correlation between EulerAngler and Quaternions, which will not work. Just to clarify, what you see in the editor is your localEulerAngle, and maybe you are asking, "if localEulerAngles is the value shown in the editor why do they differ in my code", this happens because eulerAngles does not store the X, Y, Z info, the property that you access through your code is a representation of your quaternion as angle, but the editor store the values that you insert there, and internally convert those values to a quaternion, you can read more about it in documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html

Hope this help

Comment: Hey, I actually did read that article, but (AFAIK) it does not answer my questions, which is: 1) Is it possible to get the editor values in the script? 2) if I have an editor value, how do I modify a game object to use those values

Comment: 1) AFAIK you don't have a built-in method to get the exact numbers shown in the editor because they just exist in c# and in a layer for communication between the user and the actual data, that is the quaternion.

Comment: 2) IDK if I got it right, you will be able to use it for most calculations (as shown in the documentation), just don't rely too much on values that you see in the editor

Comment: I have a simple script that rotates an object's X (0-360, then 0 again, etc). and use "transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(x,  this.transform.eulerAngles.y, this.transform.eulerAngles.z)"). I see that "this.transform.eulerAngles.y" and z changes. Why would an objects Y and Z change, if I only rotate around X. I don't get that :| they should be constant

Comment: Sometimes isnt possible to be so straightforward, as I said, the angles that you see and use as Vector3 is just a representation of Quaternion, quaternion has 4 values and the loss of this fourth dimension has removed some freedom from us, so for some rotations when you move one axis the system will move other axes to be able to represent your new rotation