# Check if y euler angle is at 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to check if my object's y rotation is 0 or not. If yes, the bool should be enabled. But this never happens even when the object's rotation is (0, 0, 0). What am I doing wrong?

```
public bool isZero = false;

void Update () {
        if(transform.eulerAngles.y == 0){
            isZero = true;
        } else {
            isZero = false;
         }
    }
```

Comment: See also: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html

Comment: no sorry i am still not able to follow this.

Comment: You cannot compare floating point value reliably using `==`. You need to use something like `Mathf.Approximately(transform.eulerAngles.y, 0.0f)` instead

Comment: isZero = Mathf.Abs(transform.eulerAngles.y) < 0.1f;  // adjust 0.1f to your liking

Comment: But what if in the inspector window it is 0 but when I debug transform.eulerAngles.y, it comes as 90. Why does this happen?

Comment: I suggest you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73753781/how-do-i-get-a-game-objects-rotation-values-that-is-displayed-in-the-editor-in unity is doing shady things in the background with transform.eulerAngles

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Comparing one component of euler angles is generally insignificant.

Comment: @Nathan it's not "shady things" ^^ there is simply many (maybe even infinite?) ways to represent a Quaternion in Euler space -> unity goes with what they consider the best human readable values